# in iText5 how to add PdfTemplate into PdfStamper if possible?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

I have a use case that I cannot figure out how to implement.

I'm using headless chrome to export a rich text editor as a pdf and then I need to cut out a part of the created PDF and embed it as a pdf annotation in another parent pdf such that the annotation looks exactly the same as the section I cut out from the created PDF.

I'm able to correctly calculate and cut the precise area I need from the created PDF using instructions provided by:
https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/stamping-content-existing-pdfs-itext5/cut-and-paste-content-page

```
PdfTemplate template2 = cb.createTemplate(pageSize.getWidth(), pageSize.getHeight());
template2.rectangle(toMove.getLeft(), toMove.getBottom(), toMove.getWidth(), toMove.getHeight());
template2.clip();
template2.newPath();
template2.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
cb.addTemplate(template1, 0, 0);
cb.addTemplate(template2, -20, -2);
```

I would like to add the PDFTemplate via a PdfStamper.

Is this possible? If not now can I achieve this with another method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you refer to, you obtain `cb` like this:

```
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
```

When using `PdfStamper`, you can obtain `cb` like this:

```
PdfContentByte cb = stamper.getUnderContent(p);
```

Or like this:

```
PdfContentByte cb = stamper.getOverContent(p);
```

The former method will add the new content *under* the existing content; the latter method will add the new content *on top of* the existing content. In these lines `p` is a page number (from 1 to the total number of pages of the existing document). See [How to superimpose pages from existing documents into another document?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-superimpose-pages-existing-documents-another-document) for an example.

If you want to add new pages to an existing document, use the `insertPage()` method as explained in [How to add blank pages to an existing PDF in java?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-blank-pages-existing-pdf-java) Once you have added a blank page, you can add a `PdfTemplate` to it.